Build multi stage Dockerfile in GCP Cloudbuild
Hi I have this Dockerfile for my NodeJS app :
ARG NODE_IMAGE=node:21.7.3-alpine
ARG PROJECT_NAME=app

FROM $NODE_IMAGE AS base
RUN apk --no-cache add dumb-init
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/$PROJECT_NAME && chown node:node /home/node/$PROJECT_NAME
WORKDIR /home/node/$PROJECT_NAME
USER node
RUN mkdir tmp

FROM base AS dependencies
COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN npm ci

FROM dependencies AS test
ENV NODE_ENV=test
RUN npm run test

FROM dependencies AS build
RUN npm run build

FROM base AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PORT=$PORT
ENV HOST=$HOST
COPY --chown=node:node ./package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --production --omit="dev"
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /home/node/$PROJECT_NAME/build .
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "dumb-init", "node", "bin/server.js" ]

I'm using Google Cloud Platform with Cloud Build to deploy my app.
Here is my cloudbuild.yaml
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: ['build', '--target', 'production' ,'-t', '$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - >-
        --image=$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
images:
  - >-
    $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
substitutions:
  _DEPLOY_REGION: europe-west1
  _AR_HOSTNAME: europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev
  _TRIGGER_ID: 437633372d-82257-4822f-95223-48b16c3337741b
  _PLATFORM: managed
  _SERVICE_NAME: app
tags:
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run
  - gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed

I want to target the docker build production stage in cloud build but it seems to run every steps and I have the test stage running also.
How can I achieve that ?
I don't have this issue when trying to target a step in my local machine
docker build --target production -t app .
docker build --target test -t app-test .
docker run -d --name app --restart always -p 3333:3333 --env-file .env app


In your example, when you run your successive docker build command, you run it in the same environment.
It's a major difference with Cloud Build because every run on Cloud build start from a clean environment. it has no knowledge on what has been done before, and what have been the images built.
Therefore, you must use a cache mechanism to save externally the state of the build and then reload it in another run of Cloud build.
To achieve this, Kaniko is the right tool to use. More info here
